# Markov chains: understanding irreducible and period definitions on example

Tags: stochastic-processes, markov-chains

Why is this Markov chain not a counter example to irreducible implying all states have the same period?

$
\begin{align}
 (p_{ij}) &= \begin{pmatrix}
 0 & \frac{1}{2}& \frac{1}{2}\\
 \frac{1}{3} & \frac{1}{3} & \frac{1}{3}\\
 \frac{1}{4} & \frac{1}{4} &\frac{1}{2}
  \end{pmatrix}
\end{align}$

This Markov chain jumps around $ \{1,2,3 \}$, and can move through states 2 and 3 into any other state, so is irreducible. However, $p^{(1)}_{11} = 0$ while $p^{(1)}_{22}$ and $p^{(1)}_{33}$ are both greater than 0 so it seems state 1 has a different period to states 2 and 3?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All states have period $1$ in your example.  Check the definition of period.  It's true that $p^{(1)}_{11} = 0$, but $p^{(n)}_{11} > 0$ for all $n \ge 2$, so the period is $1$.